# Require to create banner for my new SharePoint 2013 site

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am new to SharePoint.I need to create a banner for my site . Please find below the steps I followed.

1) Uploaded the `reuse_banner.png` file in document section (asset is the folder under document section)

2) created CSS file

```
body { 
    background:url("sites/reuse/Assets/reuse_banner.png") no-repeat fixed top; 
}
```

3) Under **`Site Settings -->Web designer galleries -->Master page and page layouts`** , created a folder named **`MyMasterStyle`** and uploaded the css file

4) Downloaded the copy of **`master.seattle`** file and edited like this

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="/MyMasterStyles/banner_test.css" runat="server" />
```

5) `Checked-In` the new **`master_new.seattle`** and published

6) Under **`Look and Feel --->  Master page`** changed the default master page to **`master_new.seattle`**.

I couldn't see the banner image on my home page.

Can some one correct me.

Comment: Can you check in developer tool if your CSS file is coming? If its not coming then probably not referred properly. Also for referring can try <style type=text/css> put your css here </style>

Answer (score 0):

to test if you are working with an invalid css reference I would:

- set the orginal master as default again
- save the original master
- edit the original master as described in [leos-sp-tips how to add site banner...](http://leos-sp-tips.blogspot.de/2015/12/how-to-add-site-banner-in-sharepoint.html)

which has two aspects

- the delegate control for the branding is deactivated
- the banner is directly referenced from the source without file link / css registration

If this test is ready 4 use you can do try-and-error to examine whether the seattle_new activation is the problem or the css registration. But don't forget to save the original seattle first in order to be able to restore it in case of crashing the file by sharepoint designer which is very easy to reach.